# How would I animate this but not move the other side of cube?

Tags: animation

I am sure this is easy but for some reason I can't think how to do this correctly.

I need the monitor to go straight up, not at an angle.

The 1st gif is exactly what I am after, the 2nd gif is what I currently have. I have parented my pieces. Do I have to use bones instead? Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hmmm no the only constraint I have ever used is a "track to" with my camera. I will have to go research how to do that.

Comment: [You're looking for Constraints](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/introduction.html). These allow you to restrict movement of objects in relation to each other or globally. [Here is a tutorial](https://vimeo.com/8885769). You can carry the methodology over to what you are working on.

Comment: I suggested rotation constraint before, and is true but probably better on a classic armature rig (with bones constraint) here you could need both FK and IK it seems...

Comment: thanks m.ardito, your 1st suggestion actually worked for what I needed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a *Limit Rotation* constraint to the piece in blue, provided the following pieces are parented in chain.

Make sure you set it to *World Space* coordinates, so it reads the absolute value instead of the parent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Duarte, I have never used constraints on anything other than my camera. Didn't realize I could use them like that too. It worked perfect.

Answer (score 2):

a possible way with armature (FK only)

constraint setup detail:

[image]

[image]

[image]

which will make it work like

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, I got the constraints working how I needed, thanks to your original comment. I will keep this in mind for future stuff.